# How to create a dialog box dynamically in MFC application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a MFC SDI application. I want to get a dialog box called on the click of a menu button  but I want to create that dialog box dynamically and not use the resource view. I am not able to figure out how to do that even after googling a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back around Visual Studio 2008, there was some sample code called [DLGTEMPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177534(v=vs.90).aspx).  I've used it to build a dynamic dialog just like you want.  I'm using VS2013 and I could not seem to find the sample code on my local hard drive.  However, Microsoft still makes this available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177534(v=vs.80).aspx) via a VS2005 samples page.  Simply click on "Download Sample" at the top and it will install the sample onto your hard drive.  The sample provides the basis for creating a dynamic dialog from an in memory resource.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2008Samples/MFC/general/dlgtempl/itemtemp.cpp

Answer (score 1):

- Create an empty dialog resource or use a empty resource template in memory.
- Create the dialog. Either using a pointer to the resource template in memory, or in the resource.
- Call DoModal.
- In OnInitDialog. Resize the dialog, Create all child windows, set the dialog title...